# Python XML parsing, lxml, urllib.request

Tags: python, xml, lxml, urllib

I am a little bit stuck trying to parse a XML file retrieved from url, my goal is to get this xml file into a well structured object to easily retrieve its data. My current code results in the following error:

```
>>> tree = etree.parse(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3299, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72421)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105883)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1817, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106182)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1721, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105181)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1122, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:100131)
  File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94254)
  File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:95690)
  File "parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94722)
OSError: Error reading file '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
```

**Code:**

```
(scraper) gmf:scr gmf$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan  2 2015, 20:14:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import urllib.request
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
>>> opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
>>> f = opener.open('https://nordfront.se/feed')
data = f.read()
f.close()
>>> tree = etree.parse(data)
```

I'm very thankful for your help

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163247/can-i-supply-a-url-to-lxml-etree-parse-on-python-3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the doc string (see `help(ET.parse)`), `ET.parse` expects the first argument
to be

- a file name/path

  ```
  import lxml.etree as ET    
  tree = ET.parse(filename)
  ```
- a file object

  ```
  with open('data.xml') as f:
      tree = ET.parse(f)
  ```
- a file-like object

  ```
  import io
  tree = ET.parse(io.BytesIO(data))
  ```
- a URL using the HTTP or FTP protocol

  ```
  import urllib.request
  opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
  tree = ET.parse(opener.open(url))
  ```

This final option, which passes `opener.open(url)` directly to `ET.parse` instead of defining `data = f.read()` is probably the option you'd want to use.

Alternatively, when you already have the XML in a string, `data`, you can use `ET.fromstring`:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
```

Note, however, that `parse` returns an `ElementTree`, while `fromstring` returns an `Element`.