# parse http[s] weboages with lxml in python

Tags: python, html-parsing, python-requests, lxml

until recently i was able to parse table data from the website [here](https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/financials?s=SUZLON:NSI&subView=IncomeStatement&periodType=q). I notice that the transmission protocol changed from `http` to `https`which i believe is the reason, the old code does not work anymore. I get this error: `IOError: Error reading file 'https:/....` my code is basically

```
import lxml.html
page = lxml.html.parse(url) 
table = [page.xpath("//tr/td/text()")
```

how can i continue to get the data from `https`webpages, preferably sticking with `lxml`?

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163247/can-i-supply-a-url-to-lxml-etree-parse-on-python-3 lxml does not support https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it this way:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import requests as r


doc = r.get(yourHttpsUrl).content
html = lh.fromstring(doc)

# now use your xpath on this `html`
```